# Compilation error when importing JS library in Ionic/TypeScript with typings

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am trying to understand how to include external js libraries to an Ionic2 project using TypeScript, and I followed instructions I found without sucess.

I am very new to Ionic and Typescript so I am guessing there's still (more than) something I am doing wrong. I am trying to use D3 library in my pages (the same happens with other libraries, I took D3 to explain).

This is what I've done so far starting from the example project:

```
ionic start mytest --v2 --ts
cd mytest
npm install d3 --save
typings install registry:dt/d3 --global --save
```

in a page I am importing d3 as follows:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
```

or
    import d3 from 'd3'

When running the application and compiling TypeScript, I get the error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3'.
```

So, from my understanding, it looks like the TS compiler is unable to find type definition files for that module. However, I assume that the typescript system that is installed together with the Ionic2 default sample, is including the type definition file (index.d.ts, referencing */// <reference path="globals/d3/index.d.ts" />*) with the line:

```
"**/*.ts",
```

under FilesGlob key in tsconfig.json. Current compiler version is 1.8.7. I also tried to reference the same file under a "files" key in tsconfig.json or the file under

```
"typings/globals/d3/index.d.ts"
```

but nothing changes. I'm still getting the same compilation error. Also, when working with Atom editor, the library is picked up correctly and members appear in auto completion list. I am unsure if the error is just related to typings or if the compiler does not find the source javascript library.

Do you have any suggestion?
Aside from this compilation exception, should I add the d3.js file in www/index.html? Or it is automatically packed (and it is unclear to me how) into application bundle javascript file (maybe there is a connection between this question and the reason of the compilation error)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, there are some files that need to be modify when we're using typings.

Take a look to this link, it was very useful for me:

http://x-team.com/2016/06/include-javascript-libraries-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project/

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can please change the title so that it is really a question?

Answer (score 0):

I had compilation errors adding the latest d3 version 4 to an Angular 2 project via npm. This might also be relevant for Ionic 2. I think there is a xhtmlrequest dependency that was causing typescript compiler issues.

I used older version of d3.jd

```
npm install --save d3@3.5.17 

typings install dt~d3 --save --global


// in the TypeScript file

import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

This worked ok